# Ionic 3 ion-datetime display format without year ngModel will blank

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngmodel

I am build up the form in ionic 3 app, and have a birthday input using ion-datetime. For some privacy reason, I can't get the people birth year. But when I set the ion-datetime format with DD MMMM. the ngModel is blank, but when I have year e.g. DD MMMM YYYY, it will normal get the user input. May I know how to solve it? below is my code:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMMM" [(ngModel)]="formData.birthday"></ion-datetime>
```

And the stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9q3aas?file=pages%2Fabout%2Fabout.html

Comment: It should work, can you create issue reproducible stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9q3aas?file=pages%2Fabout%2Fabout.html
Thanks for a reply @SivakumarTadisetti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a very strange issue!

I think the issue is because of [this line of code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/blob/master/src/components/datetime/datetime.ts#L500) of Ionic's source code:

```
_inputNgModelEvent(): any {
  return convertDataToISO(this.value);
}
```

Seems like Ionic is trying to convert the selected values to an ISO date, but if the year is not there, then it's not a valid ISO date. One workaround would be to listen to the `ionChange` event directly, like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Test
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Value</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime 
    displayFormat="DD MMMM"
    (ionChange)="updateValues($event)" <--- here!
  ></ion-datetime>

  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <button ion-button (click)="printValues()">Show Result in Console</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

And then in your component code you can handle that event to get the selected values:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
export class TestPage {
  public day: number;
  public month: number;

  updateValues(values: any) {
    if(values) {
      this.day = values.day;
      this.month = values.month;
    }
  }

  printValues() {
    console.log(`day: ${this.day}`);
    console.log(`month: ${this.month}`);
  }
}
```

Please take a look at the updated **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3-date-time-without-year?file=pages/about/about.ts)** demo.